# how to drop data of only one table in mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, shopware

My situation: a webshop running Shopware6, database quite big (34GB total) but most of it is the logs (table `log_entry` = 28GB) and the saved shopping carts (table `cart` = 3GB).

I would like to do a mysqldump but for 2 tables `log_entry` and `cart`, I would like to save only the schema.

I know how to do only the schema for all tables with the `--no-data` flag or the data only with the `--no-create-info` flag and to ignore a table with the `--ignore-table=[tablename]`.

Is my best option to do 2 dumps, one with the schema only and a second one with data only where I ignore the 2 tables?

that would then give

```
mysqldump -u user -p $dbname --no-data > backup_schema.sql
mysqldump -u user -p $dbname --no-create-info --ignore-table=$dbname.cart --ignore-table=$dbname.log_entry > backup_data.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use native mysqldump, you cannot avoid to make two calls as already mentioned by yourself.

We use the GDPRdump tool by SmileSA for such jobs, where you can leave out (truncate) and even anonymize data during the dump.

There is already a Shopware 6 template for this on GitHub
https://github.com/portaltech-reply/gdpr-dump-shopware

A less sophisticated solution which basically does what you already tried in a bit more flexible way and into one dump-file, is https://github.com/amenk/SelfScripts/blob/master/mysql-stripped-dump (self-link)

Answer (score 0):

If it works, it might be your best bet.  Although, is it possible to send it SQL statements directly in your environment? Another way might be to export the data into CSV format using an SQL statement that gets the exact data you want.  This code would get just the data (username, email and state):

```
SELECT username, email, state
FROM TABLENAME
INTO OUTFILE '/temp/yourdata.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This one will get the Columns & Data together:

```
SELECT 'username', 'email', 'state'
UNION ALL
SELECT username, email, state
FROM TABLENAME
INTO OUTFILE '/temp/yourdatafull.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I know this might not be the exact answer you were looking for, but it might give you an alternative idea for a secondary or alternative backup method.  Or at the very least it is handy to drop a file that will load easy into excel that you can play around with to do some manual calculations or data mining.  Although a drawback is I believe if you do this, it will use the first datatype when you do a join so if you have dates or numbers after it might confuse it a bit.  Also if you have the `--secure-file-priv` set to ON you will only be able to output to the specific directly specified in the MySQL settings.

Of course if you have an environment where you are saving integers and dates as strings, I think you should be fine.  Will need some testing on that for sure, just stumbled across that over here if you want more information on this method:

https://www.databasestar.com/mysql-output-file/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not exactly fitting, Shopware comes with many tables, that means the backup script will be long to write. Furthermore, adding a plugin may add a table, requiring then to amend the backup procedure which I do not want to do (I want a setup-and-forget solution).

Comment: That is the downside is that you would have to be specific with what you were grabbing, but if you eventually end up with a good SQL line to grab the data you want, it is pretty handy.  Although the reality is this method could do a fully backup, its not as efficient for that, but you don't need to use a plugin to grab data like I described above.